# monitor/gpu crashes when expanding window on dual monitor/dual AMD GPU setup

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, amdgpu

I have a new machine using Ubuntu 23.04 with dual AMD 7900 XTX GPUs.

I had 2 4k monitors connected with display port with one to each card.

If I moved a window from one screen to the other, it's fine if it's not expanded. If I expand it to the whole screen, then the monitor would turn off (likely because the GPU stopped sending signal). I had to unplug and plug back in to get it working again.

If I put both display ports into one GPU, then the problem wouldn't occur. So it only happens when each card gets a monitor, and swapping a program to a different monitor.

Any ideas where I could start to debug such a problem?